# Error: no declaration of property

Tags: objective-c

I have two properties I declare in my header file and synthesize in my class (name?) file:

- width
- height

  (hash/pound symbol)import

  ```
  @interface Rectangle : NSObject {   int width;  int height; }

  @property width, height;

  -(int) area;
  -(int) perimeter;
  -(void) setWidth: (int) w setHeight: (int) h;

  @end
  ```

.m file:

```
 (hash/pound symbol)import "Rectangle.h"
@implementation Rectangle

@synthesize width, height;
-(void) setWidth: (int) w setHeight: (int) h
{
    width = w;
    height = h;
}
-(int) area
{
    return width * height;
}
-(int) perimeter
{
    return (width + height) * 2;
}
@end
```

However, I am getting some errors:

> ```
> error: syntax error before 'width;
> error: no declaration of property 'width' found in the interface;
> error: no declaration of property 'height' found in the interface;
> ```

Please excuse the formatting I am having problems with the '#' symbol and the code formatting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised...

```
@property width, height;
```

... that even compiles.  It should be:

```
@property int width;
@property int height;
```

And you'd almost never see this:

```
-(void) setWidth: (int) w setHeight: (int) h;
```

Instead, the @property implies `setWidth:` and `setHeight:`.

Comment: @property int height,width;

Comment: @KesongXie Right.  That was why I was surprised that even compiled... that was right out of OP's code.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@interface Rectangle : NSObject 
{   
  int width;  
  int height; 
}

@property int width;
@property int height;

-(int) area;
-(int) perimeter;
-(void) setWidth: (int) w andHeight: (int) h;

@end
```